# Hash tables VS associative arrays

Tags: php, hashtable, associative-array

Recently I have read about **hash-tables** in a very famous book "[Introduction to Algorithms](http://www.introductiontoalgorithms.com/)". I haven't used them in any real applications yet, but want to. But I don't know how to start.
Can anyone give me some samples of using it, for example, how to realize a dictionary application (like ABBYY Lingvo) using hash-tables?
And finally I would like to know what is the difference between hash-tables and associative arrays in PHP, I mean which technology should I use and in which situations?
If I am wrong (I beg pardon) please correct me, because actually I am starting with hash-tables and I have just basic (theoretical) knowledge about them.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350361/how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level

Comment: For myself if I'm ever back here. PHP associative arrays are just better than Maps right now. On a benchmark test a Map used nearly twice as much memory as an associative array, and population and retrieval of all records was almost 5 times faster for the associative array.

Answer (score 137, accepted):

In PHP, associative arrays are implemented as hashtables, with a bit of extra functionality.

However technically speaking, an associative array is not identical to a hashtable - it's simply *implemented* in part with a hashtable behind the scenes. Because most of its implementation is a hashtable, it can do everything a hashtable can - but it can do more, too.

For example, you can loop through an associative array using a for loop, which you can't do with a hashtable.

So while they're similar, an associative array can actually do a **superset** of what a hashtable can do - so they're not exactly the same thing. Think of it as hashtables plus extra functionality.

Code examples:

**Using an associative array as a hashtable**:

```
$favoriteColor = array();
$favoriteColor['bob']='blue';
$favoriteColor['Peter']='red';
$favoriteColor['Sally']='pink';
echo 'bob likes: '.$favoriteColor['bob']."\n";
echo 'Sally likes: '.$favoriteColor['Sally']."\n";
//output: bob likes blue
//        Sally likes pink
```

**Looping through an associative array**:

```
$idTable=array();
$idTable['Tyler']=1;
$idTable['Bill']=20;
$idTable['Marc']=4;
//up until here, we're using the array as a hashtable.

//now we loop through the array - you can't do this with a hashtable:
foreach($idTable as $person=>$id)
    echo 'id: '.$id.' | person: '.$person."\n";

//output: id: 1 | person: Tyler
//        id: 20 | person: Bill
//        id: 4 | person: Marc
```

Note especially how in the second example, the order of each element is maintained (Tyler, Bill Marc) based on the order in which they were entered into the array. This is a major difference between associative arrays and hashtables. A hashtable maintains no connection between the items it holds, whereas a PHP associative array does (you can even sort a PHP associative array).

Comment: Hmmm, such a short explanation. So they are **ABSOLUTELY** the same thing?

Comment: @Bak They aren't in general, but they are in PHP, which plays a bit fast and loose with data structures since there's less of a concern over performance

Comment: I see, but in this case why are there so many algorithms for hash functions and stuff like that, if hash function=arrays?

Comment: @Michael you make it sound like a disadvantage? It makes PHP different, but I think it's a good difference.

Comment: @Bakhityor: I have added to my answer in response to your comment.

Comment: @incrediman. Thanks for additional info. What I have get from your explanation is that I must forget about hash-tables and use and think associative arrays, right? Because associative arrays are hashtable+extra functionality and it makes it more powerful.

Comment: @Bakhityor: Your last sentence is perfect. You don't need to 'forget' about hashtables though - in fact it's great you already understand hashtables, because now you can apply that knowledge to associative arrays. I'm adding some examples to my answer to further clarify thing for you.

Comment: @incrediman. Perfect. I am looking forward to see, analyze and remember your example in order to close this subject for myself. Thanks again, your are really **incredible man** :)

Comment: The major disadvantage to use hashtable to implement array is that there is some notable overhead behind the scene, too.
Direct array access is alway much faster than hashtable lookup, if we're counting cpu cycles.

Comment: Good answer. I would like to expand it with the fact that not only the underlying implementation of arrays in PHP are hash tables, they are also used to store almost everything else: objects' properties and methods, functions, variables. etc.

Comment: > an associative array can actually do a superset of what a hashtable can do

Hardly.  Hashtables can have keys that aren't strings!

Answer (score 23):

php arrays ARE basically hash tables

Comment: Edit: Ah - beat me to it :)

+1.

Comment: no way. a hash table would require some sort of collision resolution, which php arrays doesnt have. Their collision resolution strategy is just replacing the old value, and thats not a hash table by definition.

Comment: As far as I recall, the collision resolution in hash tables is for the _hashed_ key, not the original key (How should that even work?)

Comment: per Juan's comment: an array can be implemented as a hash table, but does not mean that it is a hash table. Arrays don't need collision detection so any underlying implementation can ignore collisions (just replace values through assignment).

Answer (score 21):

The difference between an associative array and a hash table is that an associative array is a data type, while a hash table is a data implementation.  Obviously the associative array type is very important in many current programming languages: Perl, Python, PHP, etc.  A hash table is the main way to implement an associative array, but not quite the only way.  And associative arrays are the main use of hash tables, but not quite the only use.  So it's not that they are the same, but if you already have associative arrays, then you usually shouldn't worry about the difference.

For performance reasons, it can be important to know that your associative arrays in your favorite language are implemented as hashes.  And it can be important to have some idea of the overhead cost of that implementation.  Hash tables are slower and use more memory than linear arrays as you see them in C.

Perl lumps the two concepts together by calling associative arrays "hashes".  Like a number of features of Perl, it isn't quite wrong, but it's sloppy.

Comment: Could you give an example of associative array not implemented with a hashtable?

Comment: For instance, you could implement an associative array using one or another incremental sorting algorithm, without using a hash function for the keys.

Answer (score 7):

An array in PHP is actually an ordered map, not hashtable. Main difference between map and hashtable consists in inability to remember the order in wich elements have been added. On the other hand, hashtables are much faster than maps. Complexity of fetching an element from map is O(nlogn) and from hashtable is O(1).

Comment: "Complexity of fetching an element from map is O(nlogn)" - this is simply not true. Even for a LinkedList, fetching a given element is only O(n). What is more, as addressed at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table, the hash table used in PHP to implement an associative array has lookup of O(1)

Comment: As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350361/how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level#answer-2351808) after checking the source code, associative arrays in PHP are implemented as hash tables where _"each value stored in the hash is linked to the value stored before it and the value stored after"_ as a linked list. So it uses extra memory for that, but accessing a certain element using a key is equally fast as an usual hash table, O(1), not slower.

Answer (score 3):

An associative array is an array where you don't access elements by an index, but by a key. How this works internally is implementation specific (there is no rule how it must work). An associative array could be implemented by a hash table (most implementations will do that), but it could also be implemented by some sort of tree structure or a skip list or the algorithm just iterates over all elements in the array and looks for a key that matches (this would be awfully slow, but it works).

A hash table is a way how to store data where values are associated to keys and where you intend to find values for keys within a (usually almost) constant time. This sounds exactly like what you expect of an associative array, that's why most of the time hash tables are used for implementing those arrays, but that is not mandatory.