# Array in Array PHP to Autoit

Tags: php, arrays, autoit

I have following code block in PHP:

```
$params = array( 
        'wsKey' => '5443', 
        'Number' => array('226340656'));
```

I want to convert above PHP code to AutoIt code. I tried below code

```
Local $params[2][2] = [['wsKey', '5443'], ['Number', '226340656']]
```

is it correct?

Comment: didn't get your question can u clarify it ?

Comment: [Documentation](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Arrays). Looks like they are just simple arrays (kind of like in Javascript). You need a map/dictionary type of data structure. I do not know if the language has such a thing, but if it does then it should be in the documentation somewhere; go look for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams that you cannot create the same structure on AutoIt because demonstrated structure could be represented with hashmap([php's arrays are hashmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3134315/1503018)) only. And AutoIt has none of any datatype that related to hashmap ([arrays only](https://www.autoitscript.com/wiki/Arrays)).

But you could try to find (or write) library which provides bunch of functions which help to work with variable like with hashmap([example](http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/59174-associative-array-functions/))

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your question is not clear, and the following format is wrong,

```
$params[2][2] = [['wsKey', '5443'], ['Number', '226340656']]
```

if you want to create $params[2][2] array with {{'wsKey', '5443'}, {'Number', '226340656'} data you can use the following code segment.

```
$params[] = array('wsKey', '5443');
$params[] = array('Number', '226340656');
```

If print $params then following out put will display,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => wsKey
            [1] => 5443
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Number
            [1] => 226340656
        )

)
```