# Is the following array well defined for binary search?

Tags: php, arrays, performance, binary-search

I have a file with consisted of *int;int* values in each line. Both columns are ascending, row by row. I plan to load that file into an array with following code:

```
while( ! feof($f) ) {
    $line = fgets( $f, 32 );
    $tmp = explode( ";", $line );
    $elements[] = array( $tmp[0] => $tmp[1] );
}
```

I intend to use this array to do a binary search based on the key $tmp[0]. Array will have 1000 elements, but the search will be applied for 10.000 different values. Should I simply define a 2x1000 matrix and load elements into it?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) to get the entire contents of a file as an array of lines. Assuming that the first int in each pair is unique, you can use it as the key for the array:

```
foreach (file('ints.txt') as $line) {
  list($key, $value) = explode(';', $line);
  $elements[$key] = $value;
}
```

Looking up values by their keys in `$elements` will be [O(n) but really close to O(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473989/list-of-big-o-for-php-functions); this might be fast enough for your purposes.

Comment: array in php are maps with access time O(1) (constant), not O(log(n)) (logarithmic, binary search)

Comment: @knittl Really! I always assumed PHP's arrays were implemented with a balanced tree.

Comment: thx very much. they are all unique, so that won't be a problem. also, good to know about internal representation!

Comment: @meagar: see [how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350361/how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level), arrays are HashTales (access time `O(1)`) – binary trees would still only provide logarithmic access time

Comment: @playcat Note that I've updated my answer: PHP arrays are associative, but lookups are O(1) not O(log(n)) as I erroneously assumed.

Comment: thx meagar, it's noted. i tend to carefully watch for changes on / in my questions. but, would it be more efficient to use n x 2 map?