# Converting Java hashmap initializer to PHP equivalent

Tags: java, php, hashmap, associative-array, stdclass

Just curious which way is correct?

```
// the origional JAVA method
public void setRequestHeader(String key, String value) {
    if (this.headers == null) {
        this.headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    this.headers.put(key, value);
}
```

should this be interpreted in PHP as

```
Class HashMap {}

/**
 * @return this
 */
public function setRequestHeader($key, $value) {
    if ($this->headers == NULL) {
        $this->headers = new HashMap();
    }
    return $this->headers->$key = $value;
}
```

....or....

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function setRequestHeader($key, $value) {
    if ($this->headers == NULL) {
        $this->headers = array();
    }
    return $this->headers[$key] = $value;
}
```

if the associative array is correct like I believe, would there be a need for declaring this variable at the top of the class?

```
// JAVA version
private HashMap<String, String> headers;
```

Would be akin to

```
// PHP version
private $headers = array();
```

Comment: For your second question, you don't need to declare something as an `array` before using it in PHP, so no, there isn't a "need" for it. It's probably better practice though.

Comment: Yeah it would change the second method (the associative one) to ask `if(empty($this->headers)) // do stuff` instead of `if ... == NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in PHP have a key-value structure...thus is correct:

```
$this->headers[$key] = $value;
```

In fact, the PHP manual says:

> An array in PHP is actually an ordered map.

http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Although, according to [How is the PHP array implemented on the C level?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350361/how-is-the-php-array-implemented-on-the-c-level) , it is actually a `HashTable`, which means you can rely on the O(1) lookup.

Comment: +1. I also believe this is correct, but wanted to see if anyone doesn't believe that associative arrays are PHP's equivalent of hashmaps and why. The only reason I ask is that this is in a Class related OOP scenario.

Comment: @ehime Fair enough. I figured you knew the ordered map bit, but I was surprised as well to read that they were implemented as a HashTable. Maybe this will be interesting to others as well :)

Comment: Yeah I thought that this particular scenario interesting enough to be worth asking about?