# How can I determine in PHP if it is an array or a hash?

Tags: php, arrays

I know that if you manually declare the keys in your array, it is considered hash and if it is a self-generated key, it is an array(sequential). So what if I manually declare

```
$array1 = array(1 => 123, 2 => 312, 3 => 456);
// and
$array2 = array(123,312,456);
```

Questions:

1. Is `$array1` an array or hash?
2. Is my idea on hash and array correct?

Comment: Check first comment here http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-array.php

Comment: PHP has no concept of hashes, a hash in PHP is simply an associative array.

Comment: PHP does not have a notion of hashes. You should write your own classes representing `lists` (arrays) and `hashes` (associative arrays) in PHP in order to achieve what you want.

Comment: Please, explore relative question: [Does PHP handle numerically-indexed arrays differently (internally)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15614566/1503018)

Answer (score 2):

PHP uses only associative arrays. To determine if an array *could be* an indexed array from `0` to `size - 1` eg an array where elements have been *pushed*, or added using `array[] = x`,  the only method known is to check if all keys are from `0` to `size - 1`.

(Note that an array could be built via the "associative" way (ie providing both keys and values), using incremental keys from `0`, and there is no way to determine that it was not built using the method given above (*push* or `[]`), since, anyway, that makes no difference)

```
$i = 0;
foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
  if ($key !== $i) break;  // Note the !== (not !=)
  $i++;
}

if ($i == count($array)) {
  // looks like array was built using indexing (see text above)
}
```

The final test `$i == count($array)`, if true, indicates that all keys where numeric, starting from 0, incremented by 1 for each element, until the last element.